# Error starting apache httpd-2.4.4 configured with mod_jk

Tags: apache, webserver

I'm trying to configure `mod_jk` with `httpd-2.4.4` and getting the below error when starting apache.

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 500 of /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:
Syntax error on line 2 of /usr/local/apache/conf/other/httpd-mine.conf:
    Cannot load /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_jk.so into server:
        dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_jk.so, 10):
    Symbol not found:
        _ap_log_error\n  Referenced from: /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_jk.so
        Expected in: flat namespace\n in /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_jk.so
```

How can I fix this?

I'm on **OS X 10.8.4** (12E55)

I compiled `httpd` and `mod_jk` from the source and both the build went fine.

Here's how I built and the conf info.:

```
# compile instructions for httpd
# apr, apr-util in srclib/
httpd-2.4.4$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache --with-included-apr --with-  pcre=/usr/local
httpd-2.4.4$ make
httpd-2.4.4$ sudo make install

# compile instructions for mod_jk
tomcat-connectors-1.2.37-src$ cd native
native$ ./configure CFLAGS='-arch x86_64' APXSLDFLAGS='-arch x86_64' --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs
native$ make
native$ sudo make install

#Content of /usr/local/apache/conf/other/httpd-mine.conf 
NameVirtualHost *:80
LoadModule jk_module /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_jk.so
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. I was pointing to the wrong `apxs` version (httpd-2.2) while configuring the `mod_jk` build.

```
native$ ./configure CFLAGS='-arch x86_64' APXSLDFLAGS='-arch x86_64' --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs
```

After compiling `mod_jk` with the right apxs file, `httpd` started without any issues.

```
native$ ./configure CFLAGS='-arch x86_64' APXSLDFLAGS='-arch x86_64' --with-apxs=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs
```